# Updating value of UI:InputTextArea on paste

Tags: salesforce1-app, inputtext

I have a `UI:InputTextArea` with a character count on the bottom. The problem I'm having is due to pasting on `Salesforce1`. The character count is not updated when I paste in the box. I have to press space for it to be updated. On the web app, the pasting is not an issue only on `Salesforce1`. 
Anyone have an idea?

This is how my code looks like right now :

```
<div>
<ui:inputTextArea cols="5" rows="5" maxlength="{!v.maxlength}"  keyup="{!c.commentSizeCheck}" value="" updateOn="keyup"  />
</div>
```

Update :

Tried changing attribute `updateOn` to "change" and still did not work.

controller function :

```
commentSizeCheck : function(component, event, helper) {
 if (component.isValid()) {
    var box = event.getSource();
    var text = box.get("v.value");
    component.set("v.textValue", text);
    text = text.replace(/\n/g, "");
    var len = text.length;
    var max = component.get("v.maxlength");
    if(len <= max) 
       component.set("v.size", max-len)
    else 
       console.log("Component problem");
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

that is because you are using `keyup` to trigger your method, instead try `change` which will trigger when you change the content of the input.

from the [ui:inputTextArea](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_ui_inputTextArea.htm) documentation:

> change    --> The event fired when the user changes the content of the input.
>
> keyup --> The event fired when the user releases a keyboard key
>   on the component.

- Make sure you define what "not works means",
- Your value attribute is an empty string, try binding it dynamically in your  code.